# How to use iOS system font and material icon-font together in UILabel

Tags: ios, icon-fonts, google-material-icons

I am using system font in `UILabel`. I have to use icon-font for some icons within text. Content of `UILabel` is dynamic and fetched from server. Alpha-numeric characters should use system font and icons should use icon-font. It's something similar to iOS showing text & emoji together.

I found some ways to do it:

1. Use icon-font as font of `UILabel`. Here I can not specify font for text
2. Use `NSAttributedString` to assign different font for text and icons

Is there a better way of doing this?